# Is there a difference between int (*p) and int *p?

Tags: c++, pointers

I just learned about function pointers and that to declare one, you must put the `*` in parentheses with the pointer name to make sure it doesn't  return an `int *`.

Is there a difference between

```
int *p
```

and

```
int (*p)
```

I tried looking this up with cdecl, but no luck so far. cdecl says it is the same thing, but doesn't provide an explanation. If I declared

```
short (*p)
```

Would that be a short pointer or a pointer to a short? Would `p` have a size of 2 bytes or 4? I know similar questions have been asked, but I've had no luck with them so far.

Comment: short pointer? I don't think it exists

Comment: @Xiaotian Pei I meant would be a short data type, or a short* data type?

Comment: The very useful tool `cdecl` says: `cdecl> explain int (*p)` `declare p as pointer to int` and `cdecl> explain int *p` `declare p as pointer to int`. You should download [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) (often available through a package manager on Linux), it's quite useful.

Comment: Just for laughs, you can also define `int (((((i)))));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would there be a difference between
>
> ```
> int *p
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int (*p)
> ```

No.  Those are two different ways of writing the same type.  The parentheses are not magic here -- they just serve to override precedence, just as with arithmetic operators.

The difference is between

```
int *p();
```

(declaration of a function "p" returning `int *`) and

```
int (*p)();
```

(declaration of a pointer to a function returning `int`).  Absent the parentheses around `*p`, the (empty) parameter list associates more tightly with the name being declared.

> If I did:
>
> ```
> short (*p)
> ```
>
> Would be be a short pointer, or a pointer to a short? And would `p` be 2 bytes, or 4?

Analogous to `int (*p)` it declares a pointer to a `short`.  The size of the pointer is implementation-specific, but 4 bytes and 8 bytes are common choices.  The pointed-to data is expected to be the size of a `short`, which is also implementation-specific, but is often 2.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of near vs. far pointers is a compiler vendor specific concept (and rarely occurs outside of some strange embedded systems nowadays; x86 machines dropped it when they moved to 32 bit IIRC). There is not, nor has there every been a concept of a "short pointer" declared using `short` (meaning a smaller than normal pointer), because C's `short` already has a meaning. A `short*` is a normal sized pointer that points to a `short` sized location, that's all.

Basically, `sometype (*p)` doesn't mean anything different from `sometype *p`. Function pointers are declared with `somereturntype (*p)(argument, types, go here)`; without the parens for argument types, it's not a function pointer at all.

Comment: I know there is no such thing as a short pointer, I just worded it wrong. I just wanted to know if there was any difference between the two. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    short (*p);
    short *r;
   printf("size - %u- %u",sizeof(p) , sizeof(r));
   return 0;
}
```

returns 4 for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

`short (*p)`

That would be a pointer to a short. Which in most cases is 2 bytes when it is de-referenced. A pointers size will probably be either 4 or 8 bytes on a modern machine.

```
s = 5;
short *p = &s;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the context you are using it in.

Parenthesis are used to force operator precedence.  If there is no need for parenthesis, such as in initialization, both `short *p` and `short (*p)` are equivalent (both are pointers to `short` values in memory).  The actual size of pointers should be uniform (and do not correspond in size to the data members they point to) as they simply store the address of the data member in question.

It is possible that you will need to use parentheses to force precedence if you have pointers to objects.  For example:

```
Object *myObject = new Object();
int myObjectSize = *myObject.size(); // INCORRECT: . operator has higher precedence than *
int myObjectSize = (*myObject).size(); // CORRECT: parentheses force precedence
```

Of course, in this specific situation, `myObject->size()`  is more commonly used (to avoid using parentheses excessively).